# magento 2 - How to get attribute set name in product listing and product detail page

Tags: magento2, product, attribute-set

How can we retrieve **the attribute set name** for a product. I want to use it on **product detail and listing page**.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We can use `\Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface` to get attribute set name.

### Detail Page

We need to override the `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` block. Inject this class on the constructor

```
/** @var \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSet **/
protected $attributeSet;

public function __construct(
    ......
    \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSet
    ......
) {
   ......
   $this->attributeSet = $attributeSet;
}


//Build method to get attribute set
public function getAttributeSetName() {

    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $attributeSetRepository = $this->attributeSet->get($product->getAttributeSetId());
    return $attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName();
}
```

Now, we can call in product detail page: `$block->getAttributeSetName();`

### Listing page

We need to override `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` block

```
/** @var \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSet **/
protected $attributeSet;

public function __construct(
    ......
    \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSet
    ......
) {
   ......
   $this->attributeSet = $attributeSet;
}

public function getAttributeSetName($product) {

    $attributeSetRepository = $this->attributeSet->get($product->getAttributeSetId());
    return $attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName();
}
```

We can call `$block->getAttributeSetName($_product)`.

Comment: $attributeSet and $product are undefined variables, I am very new to magento2 and I am not able to understand what exactly I need to write

Comment: You can see my updated answer. Enough for you?

Comment: I'm trying to implement it in product list block, but it is not working as exact, making some modifications

Comment: I'm getting error object dom should be created

Comment: You can update your answer with current issue when following my answer.

Comment: yes, indeed. But, I need to resolve it

Comment: Yeah! I believe my codes will work if implementing correctly. Actually, you can use object manager directly on your template for testing purpose. It's better if you want to test my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45831/discussion-between-abhishek-dhanraj-shahdeo-and-khoa-truongdinh).

Comment: Why did you name the attribute set repository $attributeSet and then output the attribute set to a variable named $attributeSetRepository? This is horrible!!