# Magento 2 : How to get the product attributes based on attribute set id on listing page

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, attribute-set

I am trying to get product attribute in product listing page based on attribute set id but its not working properly. can anyone help on this.

```
 $attributes = $_product->getAttributes();

  foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
// var_dump($attribute->getAttributeModel());
   $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
   if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) {
       echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel().' : '.$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) . '
';
   }
  }
```

Comment: have you set for attributes, //Product attributes -> Storefrontend Properties -> Used in Product Listing Set To Yes from admin?

Comment: yes i have already set that.my attributes are also coming but  need to show attributes based on attributeset.

Comment: pls refer this - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137917/magento-2-how-to-get-attribute-set-name-in-product-listing-and-product-detail

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should use **Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeManagementInterface** to get all attributes by attribute set id

To do this, we need to override **Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct** class and inject this class into the constructor. See more detail here:

> 1. app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="YourVendor\YourModule\Block\Catalog\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>
```

> 2. app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/Block/Catalog/Product/ListProduct.php

```
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeManagementInterface;

class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    private $attributeManagement;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PostHelper $postDataHelper
     * @param Resolver $layerResolver
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param Data $urlHelper
     * @param AttributeManagementInterface $attributeManagement
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        Resolver $layerResolver,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        Data $urlHelper,
        AttributeManagementInterface $attributeManagement,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->attributeManagement = $attributeManagement;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $postDataHelper,
            $layerResolver,
            $categoryRepository,
            $urlHelper,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get Attributes by Attribute Set ID
     * @param $attributeSetId
     * @return \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeInterface[]
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getAttributesBySetId($attributeSetId)
    {
        $attributes = $this->attributeManagement->getAttributes(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            $attributeSetId);
        return $attributes;
    }
}
```

> 3. app/design/frontend/YourCustomTheme/templates/product/list.phtml

```
........
<?php $attributes = $block->getAttributesBySetId($_product->getAttributeSetId()); ?>
                <?php
                foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                    echo ($attribute->getFrontendLabel()).':::';
                }
                ?>
..........
```

Hopefully this will solve your issue

Regards