# M2 - Get attribute set ID

Tags: magento2, attribute-set

I've looked through different posts and options but nothing that fits my question.

How can I get the Attribute set ID of the current product on the product detail page?

Comment: Have you used $product->getAttributeSetId();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this block `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View`

```
$product = $this->getProduct();
$product->getAttributeSetId();
```

follow this
[magento 2 - How to get attribute set name in product listing and product detail page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137917/magento-2-how-to-get-attribute-set-name-in-product-listing-and-product-detail#137919)